# Is it possible to distinguish between attachments added with drag and drop and via the attachment menu button

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, email-attachments

I have an outlook add-in that handles email attachments. I have my own ribbon button to add attachments but I would like to catch attachments added via drag and drop while ignoring attachments added using the standard attachment button.

It is easy enough to implement a ItemEvents_10_BeforeAttachmentAddEventHandler() but I know of no way to distinguish between attachments added with drag and drop and via the attachment menu button.

Is this possible?

Is it possible to handle the drag and drop event directly my self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOM won't help you here.
In theory, you can overwrite the Outlook drag/drop handler.

1. Get the Inspector's window handle using the `IOleWindow` interface (you can cast `Inspector` object to `IOleWindow`).
2. Get the existing drag/drop handler using `GetProp(hwnd, "OleDropTargetInterface")` Windows API - cast the returned value to `IDropTarget` interface. You probably need to experiment with which child window of the inspector is the drag/drop target you want.
3. Call `RevokeDragDrop` / `RegisterDragDrop` passing your own implementation of `IDropTarget`. That implementation can then (after doing what you need to do) call the original `IDropTarget` interface to let Outlook proceed with the default behavior.

Comment: I think I have found the correct window, or at least one that handles drag and drop but my problem now is very basic, GetProp() returns a IntPtr but I have not figured out how to cast that to a IDropTarget.

Comment: Use Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown()

Comment: I seem to be still having problems getting or setting the IDropTarget. In the following code casting the object to IDropTarget results in an exception which say "No such interface supported". Here is some code showing what I am doing:  
  
IntPtr targetPtr = GetProp(ptr, "OleDropTargetInterface");   
if (targetPtr != IntPtr.Zero) {   
IDropTarget t = (IDropTarget) Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr);   
}

Comment: Hmm... I don't know - I only did this in Delphi (which is a lot more COM friendly).

Comment: have you tried to use Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown?

Comment: Yes I tried that also with the same result. This call  
object o = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr)  
returns an object of type System._ComObject but then I am unable to do anything with it. I am doing all of this from with in my setup of my InspectorWrapper which is being called from my event handler for Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler incase this is relevant.

Comment: What does Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr, typeof(IDropTarget)) return?

Comment: Where and how did you declare IDropTarget?

Comment: It is System.Windows.Form.IDropTarget.    Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr, typeof(IDropTarget)) returns an exception: Unable to cast object System._ComObject to  System.Windows.Form.IDropTarget..

Comment: I have asked a separate question now that just deals with this problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54716854/why-am-i-unable-to-convert-the-value-returned-by-getpropptr-oledroptargetinte?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I am using the wrong IDropTarget interface aren't I? I should be using Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IDropTarget?

Comment: Yes, you want the COM interface, not the .Net specific one.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a way to distinguish between attachments added with drag and drop and via the attachment menu button without having to overwrite the drag/drop handler.

When attachments are added via drag and drop the Outlook app is not in the foreground so it has no active window.

In my BeforeAttachmentAdd() event handler I perform the following test:

```
IntPtr hWnd = GetActiveWindow();                
if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) {
// Handle drag and drop attachment
}
```

Comment: This is not reliable because there are cases where the app can be in the foreground when the drag&drop attachment is added. But it is a quick solution that will work 90% of the time. (Read: this is a hack.)