# Why am I unable to convert the value returned by GetProp(ptr, "OleDropTargetInterface") to an IDropTarget?

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to implement my own drag&drop handler for Outlook and am unable to get past the first step so far. I have an Outlook Addin that handles attachments but I would like to be able to handle attachments added via drag&drop while allowing attachments added via the normal attachment button to be added in the normal way. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451041/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-between-attachments-added-with-drag-and-drop-and-v/54451266?noredirect=1#comment96182326_54451266)

The first step is to get the following block of code to work but so far every attempt I have made fails:

```
IntPtr targetPtr = GetProp(ptr, "OleDropTargetInterface");
if (targetPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    try
    {
        object o = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr);
        string str = o.ToString(); // type is system._ComObject

        IDropTarget t;
        //t = (IDropTarget) Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr) ;
        //t = (IDropTarget) Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr, typeof(IDropTarget)) ; throws exception
        // t = (IDropTarget)Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(o, typeof(IDropTarget)); // bad parameter, type must be a ComObject type
        t = (IDropTarget)EnterpriseServicesHelper.WrapIUnknownWithComObject(targetPtr);
        //IDropTarget t = (IDropTarget)EnterpriseServicesHelper.WrapIUnknownWithComObject(targetPtr);

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        TDAddIn.showMessage(ex.ToString(), "Exception");
    }
```

}

All of my attempts result in the error that the interface doesn't exist.

The following is the complete code to my Inspector wrapper:

While testing I also tried just ignoring the existing IDropTarget and replacing it with my own but that just crashed Outlook when I dragged a file into it before my handler was called.

```
internal class InspectorWrapper
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetProp(IntPtr hWnd, string lpString);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr i);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a list of child windows
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parent">Parent of the windows to return</param>
        /// <returns>List of child windows</returns>
        public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
        {
            List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
            GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
            try
            {
                EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
                EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                    listHandle.Free();
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Callback method to be used when enumerating windows.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">Handle of the next window</param>
        /// <param name="pointer">Pointer to a GCHandle that holds a reference to the list to fill</param>
        /// <returns>True to continue the enumeration, false to bail</returns>
        private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
        {
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
            List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
            if (list == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
            }
            list.Add(handle);
            //  You can modify this to check to see if you want to cancel the operation, then return a null here
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delegate for the EnumChildWindows method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">Window handle</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">Caller-defined variable; we use it for a pointer to our list</param>
        /// <returns>True to continue enumerating, false to bail.</returns>
        public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr parameter);

        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        static extern int RegisterDragDrop(IntPtr hwnd, IDropTarget pDropTarget);

        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        static extern int RevokeDragDrop(IntPtr hwnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, [Out] StringBuilder lParam);

        const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
        const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;

        public static string GetWindowTextRaw(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            // Allocate correct string length first
            int length = (int)SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, null);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)sb.Capacity, sb);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public class myIDropTarget: IDropTarget
        {
            //IDropTarget original;

            public myIDropTarget()
            {
                //original = o;
            }
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Raises the System.Windows.Forms.Control.DragDrop event.
            //
            // Parameters:
            //   e:
            //     A System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs that contains the event data.
            public void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
            {
            }
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Raises the System.Windows.Forms.Control.DragEnter event.
            //
            // Parameters:
            //   e:
            //     A System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs that contains the event data.
            public void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
            {
            }
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Raises the System.Windows.Forms.Control.DragLeave event.
            //
            // Parameters:
            //   e:
            //     An System.EventArgs that contains the event data.
            public void OnDragLeave(EventArgs e)
            {

            }
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Raises the System.Windows.Forms.Control.DragOver event.
            //
            // Parameters:
            //   e:
            //     A System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs that contains the event data.
            public void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
            {

            }

        }
        ///=======================================

        Outlook.Inspector inspector;
        mailItemWrapper mailItemWrapper;
        myIDropTarget myDropTarget;
        bool isSet;

        void setupDragAndDrop()
        {
            if (isSet)
                return;
            isSet = true;
            IOleWindow win = (IOleWindow)inspector;
            IntPtr hWnd;
            win.GetWindow(out hWnd);
            if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int cnt = 0;
                List<IntPtr> list = GetChildWindows(hWnd);
                foreach (IntPtr ptr in list)
                {
                    if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        string btitle = GetWindowTextRaw(ptr);
                        IntPtr targetPtr = GetProp(ptr, "OleDropTargetInterface");
                        if (targetPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            cnt++;
                            try
                            {
                                int rtc = -1;
                                object o = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr);
                                string str = o.ToString(); // type is system._ComObject

                                IDropTarget t;
                                //t = (IDropTarget) Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr) ;
                                //t = (IDropTarget) Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr, typeof(IDropTarget)) ; throws exception
                                // t = (IDropTarget)Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(o, typeof(IDropTarget)); // bad parameter, type must be a ComObject type
                                t = (IDropTarget)EnterpriseServicesHelper.WrapIUnknownWithComObject(targetPtr);
                                //IDropTarget t = (IDropTarget)EnterpriseServicesHelper.WrapIUnknownWithComObject(targetPtr);
                                //rtc = RevokeDragDrop(ptr);
                                rtc = RegisterDragDrop(ptr, myDropTarget);

                            }
                            catch (System.Exception ex)
                            {
                                TDAddIn.showMessage(ex.ToString(), "Exception");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                /*
                IntPtr targetPtr = GetProp(hWnd, "OleDropTargetInterface");
                if (targetPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    IDropTarget t = (IDropTarget)Marshal.PtrToStructure(targetPtr, typeof(IDropTarget));
                }
                */
            }

        }
        public InspectorWrapper(Outlook.Inspector _inspector, Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
        {
            inspector = _inspector;
            mailItemWrapper = new mailItemWrapper(mailItem);
            myDropTarget = new myIDropTarget();
            isSet = false;

            ((Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_Event)inspector).Close += new Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_CloseEventHandler(handleClose);
            ((Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_Event)inspector).Activate += new Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_ActivateEventHandler(Activate);
            //setupDragAndDrop();
        }

        void Activate()
        {
            setupDragAndDrop();
        }
        void handleClose()
        {
            mailItemWrapper.resetMailItem(null);
            ((Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_Event)inspector).Close -= new Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_CloseEventHandler(handleClose);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was using the wrong IDropTarget I was using  `System.Windows.Form.IDropTarget` when I should have been using  `Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IDropTarget`